# Header stays while bottom of the site scrolls

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to achieve the effect they have on google ventures [site](http://www.googleventures.com/), where the user can scroll the bottom of the page while it slowly shows the effect of sliding over the header.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Many Thanks.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that, you can achieve it with pure CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by making a section of website position fixed. Its something like this

```
<div class="sec1"></div> 
<div class="sec2"></div>

.sec1 {
 position: fixed;
....
....
}
```

Comment: .sec2 { position:relative; z-index:1; }

Comment: @loris yes... @ Steve study the website using Google web inspector. you will see the magic

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">

    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    width: 300px;
}

.container
{
    position: relative;
    height: 1000px;
}

.header
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

.content
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-top: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Working copy can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mDP3y/

Comment: This is exactly the opposite

Comment: Oh, this is how I understood the question atleast.